# Ajax returns success even no data filled in form, Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have simple registration form for model. I have set up multiple validations in model.

**Idea is** : When registration is successfull, Jquery hides registration form and displays hidden div. Pretty usual thing.

**Problem:**  When I hit submit button without any data filled in it still hides form and displays success message from hidden div.

I have used the same code for other similair things and there it works perfect. But not in registration form.

**My form:**

```
    <%= form_for(resource, :builder => Judge::FormBuilder,:html => {:multipart => true,:remote =>true,:format => :json, name: "reg_form", id:"advertisement_registration_form"}, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                .....

     <div class="name-input-reg">
        <div class="pull-left">                               
                <%= f.text_field :name , :validate => true,:placeholder=>"  Vārds latviešu valodā*"%>
                <%= error_span(@advertisement[:name]) %>   
        </div>     
         <div class="pull-right">    
              <%= f.text_field :name, :validate => true,:placeholder=>"  Vārds krievu valodā*"%>
                <%= error_span(@advertisement[:name]) %>
          </div>
    </div> 
           ......

      <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service, :validate => true%> Izlasiju un piekritu <%= link_to "lietošanas noteikumiem", rules_path, :target => '_blank'%> 


         <button name="name" id="submitbutton" value="value" type="submit"><span>Pievienot</span></button>

<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
    def create

   @advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params.merge(service_ids: params[:service_ids], hour_ids: params[:hour_ids]))

         require 'securerandom'
           @advertisement.password = SecureRandom.hex(8)
           @advertisement.password_confirmation = @advertisement.password
   respond_to do |format|

        if @advertisement.save
           if params[:images]

           params[:images].each { |image|
              @advertisement.pictures.create(image: image)
           }
             end 
            AdvertisementFreeRegistered.advertisement_free(@advertisement).deliver
             format.html { redirect_to @advertisement, notice: 'Advertisement was successfully created.' }
             format.json { render json: @advertisement }


        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: @advertisement.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }

        end
    end
end
```

**My script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("ajaxSuccess", "form.reg_form", function(event, xhr, settings) {

         $(".hidde-reg").hide();

        $('.progress-bar-image').children('img').attr('src', '/assets/progress-bar-right.png');
         $(".reg-successfull").show();
            $('.form-top').children('h1').css('color', '#9EA19D');
           $('.form-top2').children('h1').css('color', '#56B0E8');

  });
  return $(document).bind("ajaxError", "form.reg_form", function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
      alert("Error.");
  });
});
```

**Console response:**

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/ru/advertisements".
```

**My app logs:**

```
Processing by Advertisements::RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "advertisement"=>{"name"=>"", "region_id"=>"", "country_id"=>"1", "age"=>"", "height"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "weight"=>"", "work1"=>"", "work2"=>"", "work3"=>"", "work4"=>"", "email"=>"", "description"=>"", "description_ru"=>"", "terms_of_service"=>"1", "humanizer_answer"=>"", "humanizer_question_id"=>"11", "your_ip"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "toggler"=>"1", "authenticity_token"=>"phH4RA/bbi3ocsZvcAmx5msh7BvLbwKNpvY84oEat3Q=", "name"=>"value", "locale"=>"ru"}

[1m[35mAdvertisement **Exists** (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `advertisements`  WHERE `advertisements`.`email` = BINARY '' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m

Completed 200 OK in 403ms (Views: 289.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
```

As I Can see from this log, my app didn't save new registration. But why Ajax response is still success?

I am confused, because this exact code worked in other places.

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first port of call in this is always to look at the response in the network tab - you can see the status code in there.  If it is a 422 or whatever, then at least you know rails is doing what you expect.  I'd expect jquery to treat any 4* status as a failed request, but i've not used the approach you are using here.

Comment: @MaxWilliams  I see there 'Status Code:200 OK'   It means problem is in Rails code ?

Comment: Yep.  Either it's saving ok, and thus returning the standard 200, or it's not saving, and doing the "else" block, and `status: :unprocessable_entity` isn't doing what you expect.  I would put some logging in at this point.  Also, try `status: 422` instead.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Tried your solution, but no change.

Comment: Is it definitely doing the else block?  Did you put some logging in?